# How to detect what commit a branch has been created from in LibGit2Sharp

Tags: git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

So given an instance of LibGit2Sharp `Branch` how do you work out what commit that it was initially created from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Branch` is merely an object depicting a git `head` reference. A `head` is a text file, mostly living under the `.git/refs/heads` hierarchy. This text file contains the hash of the `commit` this `head` currently points to. Similarly, a `Branch` bears a `Tip` property which points to a `Commit`.

When working with git repositories and performing actions such as committing, resetting, rebasing... the `head` file is updated with different hashes, pointing to different commits.

A `head` keeps no track of previous pointed at commits. Neither does the `Branch`.

With git, when creating a new branch, a new reflog is created. Git takes care of adding a first entry with a message identifying the object the branch has been created from.

Given an existing branch `backup`

```
$ cat .git/refs/heads/backup
7dec18258252769d99a4ec9c82225e47d58f958c
```

Creating a new branch will create and feed its reflog

```
$ git branch new_branch_from_branch backup

$ git reflog new_branch_from_branch
7dec182 new_branch_from_branch@{0}: branch: Created from backup
```

Of course, that also works when directly creating a branch from a commit

```
$ git branch new_branch_from_sha 191adce

$ git reflog new_branch_from_sha
191adce new_branch_from_sha@{0}: branch: Created from 191adce
```

LibGit2Sharp exposes the reflog as well. For instance, the following code will enumerate the log entries for a specific `Branch`.

```
var branch = repository.Head; // or repository.Branches["my_branch"]...

foreach (ReflogEntry e in repository.Refs.Log(branch.CanonicalName))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} : {2}",
        e.From.ToString(7), e.To.ToString(7), e.Message);
}
```

---

So "good news", the reflog may contain what you're after ;-)

but...

- you'll have to find out the correct entry by yourself by searching within each message the *"branch: Created from"* pattern
- If your branch is too old, older entries in the reflog may have been removed by the built-in **[git gc](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc)** housekeeping process (by default reflog entries are kept for 90 days) and the initial *"Created from"* entry may now be lost

**Note:** As of today, LibGit2Sharp doesn't **create** an entry when creating or removing a branch. However, this is currently tackled by the amazing **[@dahlbyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54249/dahlbyk)** as part of **[Pull Request #499](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/499)**

Comment: I had the same problem as the OP and followed your guidelines, however I noticed that in my repo, the branch reflog stops at the point where the branch was created (e.g. it did not show history from before) and it would have a 'From' value of 0. Am I missing something here? It seems like a much cleaner way to detect the start of the life of the branch rather than to search the individual commit texts.